# What is meaning of numbers to Sending in ajax function?

Tags: php, jquery

I wrote basicly ajax function in my project and then i opened firebug and i saw this number
I want to know what is number is sending or what is meaning of number. Thanks you very much.

[image]

Example Code :

```
$(".index_page").click(function(){

  $.ajax({

    url: "ajax/index.php",
    cache: false

  }).done(function( raw_html ){

    $("#content").empty();
    $("#content").append(raw_html);

  });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Jquery documnetaiton](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> cache (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')
>   Type: Boolean
>   If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already been requested by a GET.

Answer (score 4):

That is because of `cache: false` - This will add a unique parameter (*such as current time*) into your request url just to make sure browser do not serve the request from cache

Answer (score 1):

This number is there to provide actual results, not cached. It appears when you set `cache: false` in you ajax request.